# I am not using web.xml as using servlet container version 3, in tomcat 7 with Spring mvc. But maven expects web/xml?

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, web.xml

this seems rather hacky if added to POM :

```
<configuration> 
  <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you create web configuration class to implements `WebApplicationInitializer`if you have this class it should not ask about web.xml